# Array search and sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, search

Hi I have an array as shown:

```
var mainArray = ['Adam', 'Bailey', 'Cathy', 'Dave', 'Earl', 'Fernando', 'Gary', 'Harper'];
```

And I have an array of names I want to search from main array:

```
var searchArray = ['Fernando', 'Harper'];
```

I want a new array which should search 'Fernando' and 'Harper' add it to new array and then add the rest of the array to it.

```
var newArrAfterSearch = ['Fernando', 'Harper', 'Adam', 'Bailey', 'Cathy', 'Dave', 'Earl', 'Gary']
```

Tried a few things unsuccessfully like:

```
var newArrAfterSearch = [];
mainArray.forEach(name => 
 var nameFound = searchArray.find(searchName => searchName === name);
 if(nameFound) {
   newArrAfterSearch = [... mainArray, nameFound];
 }
)
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `includes`, filter out all the values from mainArray which appears in `searchArray`, then merge `searchArray` with `mainArray`

```js
const mainArray = ['Adam', 'Bailey', 'Cathy', 'Dave', 'Earl', 'Fernando', 'Gary', 'Harper'];
const searchArray = ['Fernando', 'Harper'];

const rest = mainArray.filter(v => !searchArray.includes(v))
console.log([...searchArray, ...rest])
```

---

If your searchArray has values which are not available in mainArray, while filtering values from mainArray we can keep track of occurred values and while merging we can filter searchArray as well

```js
const mainArray = ['Adam', 'Bailey', 'Cathy', 'Dave', 'Earl', 'Fernando', 'Gary', 'Harper'];
const searchArray = ['Fernando', 'Harper', 'something random'];

const mapper = Object.create(null)
const rest = mainArray.filter(v =>{
 mapper[v] = true
 return !searchArray.includes(v)
})
console.log([...searchArray.filter(v=> mapper[v]), ...rest])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partition function using `Array.reduce()`, and then flatten the results with `Array.flat()`.

The `partition()` function takes a predicate, and returns an array with 2 sub arrays. Any item that the predicate returned `true` form would be pushed to the 1st sub array (index 0), and all others to the 2nd sub array (index 1).

```js
const mainArray = ['Adam', 'Bailey', 'Cathy', 'Dave', 'Earl', 'Fernando', 'Gary', 'Harper'];
const searchArray = ['Fernando', 'Harper'];

const partition = (predicate, arr) =>
  arr.reduce((r, s) => {   
    r[predicate(s) ? 0 : 1].push(s);
    
    return r;
  }, [[], []]);

const result = partition(s => searchArray.includes(s), mainArray)
  .flat();
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `forEach` to iterate the search array, `splice` to delete the item, and `unshift` to add it again at the beginning will be straight forward:

```js
var mainArray = ['Adam', 'Bailey', 'Cathy', 'Dave', 'Earl', 'Fernando', 'Gary', 'Harper'];
var searchArray = ['Fernando', 'Harper'];
searchArray.reverse().forEach(v => {
  var index = mainArray.indexOf(v);
  if(-1 !== index){
    mainArray.splice(index, 1);
    mainArray.unshift(v);
  }
})
console.log(mainArray);
```